# how to style razor forEach inline check boxes

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, materialize

I am trying to style razor syntax with materialize css. this is what I have right now. Which doesn't work, the check boxes cannot be checked.

[image: currentCheckboxes]

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
       {
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" />
          @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
        }
 </div>
</div>
```

this is what I need to have, the issue is every check box that i check always checks Admin. I know its because the loop is naming the id and for the same for all check boxes. also I would like the closer to there check boxes

[image: whatIwantToHaveWork]

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
        {
           <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" />
           @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @for = "filled-in-box" })
       }
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: your loop is assigning the same id for all inputs. Try using `@Html.CheckboxFor`

Comment: Why dont you put checked="checked" in the input?

Comment: As you are using bootstrap please visit the following link -> http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios

Comment: @jbutler483 how would I do that?

Comment: @AmmarCSE  I don't want them all checked by default. is that what you are aiming for?

Comment: @texas697: If I remember correctly, you do the same as you did for the label, but use `@Html.CheckboxFor(...item.Id...)`

Comment: @jbutler483 item.id is not valid. this is the error message     'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do add some unique property value and create unique id like `"filled-in-box-"+item.id`.

Here in example, I have suffixed `item.id` to create unique id.

```
@foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box-@item.id" />
    @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @for = "filled-in-box-"+item.id })
}
```

OR

---

Just get rid of `@HTML.Label` and use

```
<label>
    @item.Value <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="filled-in" />
</label>
```

Comment: your first option gives me this message    'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: second option does not display any checkboxes

Comment: using item.Value is not allowing the check boxes to be checked. I posted screenshots of css from console. I think it might be a issue using bootstrap and materialize. problem is I need to use both. For issues I have been disabling what ever is causing confilcts in the style sheets. I dont know what to change with this situation though.

Comment: @texas697, My bad use `id="filled-in-box-@item.id"`, then use first one